# React Native change video link

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with a content with dual link. Firstly I play link named *"ABC"*, after 20 sec, I want to switch to play link named *"DEF"* and start at 20 sec instead of reset to 0. I used react-native-video plugins.

Can you help me solve this problem?

```
<Video source={{uri: this.state.link}}
                 ref={videoPlayer => this.videoPlayer = videoPlayer}
                 rate={this.state.rate}                     // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
                 volume={Math.max(Math.min(1, volume), 0)}                  // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
                 muted={false}                  // Mutes the audio entirely.
                 paused={this.state.paused}                // Pauses playback entirely.
                 resizeMode={resizeMode}            // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
                 repeat={true}                  // Repeat forever.
                 progressUpdateInterval={250.0} // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
                 onLoadStart={this.loadStart}   // Callback when video starts to load
                 onLoad={this.onVideoLoad}
                 onProgress={this.onProgress}      // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
                 onEnd={this.onVideoEnd}            // Callback when playback finishes
                 onError={this.videoError}      // Callback when video cannot be loaded
                 onTimedMetadata={this.onTimedMetadata}
                 onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
                 style={[backgroundVideo, backgroundHeightVideo]} />
```

[image: Video 1 screenshot]

[image: Video 2 screenshot]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Which module you are using for playing video?